# Typescript class malfunctions when used as a type in another class's property

Tags: typescript, oop, mediasoup

I'm using mediasoap and typescript in an express server application and here's the `Broadcast` type that i defined which has a property of type `Router` (a class defined in mediasoup module) and here's the problem:

Upon creating an instance of broadcast the router does not get created properly and here's why:

1. I cannot log the created object in console (`console.log` output: `[object Object]`)
2. There's an array as a 3rd level nested property in router object called `codecs`, which is very important and it doesn't get set upon creation.

But when I create the router object separately it works just fine! even if I create the broadcast object with a null value for the router and then set the router property with the separately created fine working router object it again stops behaving properly

Broadcast Class:

```
import { types } from "mediasoup";

export class Broadcast {
  Id: string;
  Title: string;
  Router: types.Router;
  Streamer: Streamer;
  Participants: Array<Participant>;
}
```

Here's a scenario to demonstrate the problem

BroadcastService Class:

```
export class BroadcastService {

  _streamerService: StreamerService;

  constructor() {
    this._streamerService = new StreamerService();
  }
  
  async CreateBroadcast(title: string, streamer: Streamer): Promise<Broadcast> {

    var broadcast: Broadcast = {
      Title: title,
      Id: uuidv4(),
      Streamer: this._streamerService.CreateStreamer(streamer.Id),
      Router: null,
      Participants: new Array<Participant>()
    };
    return broadcast;
  }
}
```

Separated Instantiation:

```
var broadcast = await broadcastService.CreateBroadcast();
console.log(broadcast.Router); // null due to Broadcast constructor
var mediaCodecs = config.router.mediaCodecs;
var router = await this.Worker.createRouter({ mediaCodecs });
console.log(router.rtpCapabilities.codecs); // logs the correct codecs
broadcast.Router = router;
console.log(broadcast.Router.rtpCapabilities.codecs); // result: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: Your examples don't show how the classes are actually instantiated. Broadcast does not have a constructor, none of its properties are initialized.

Comment: @p4m there's no constructor in Broadcast class because the object instantiation is handled in BroadcastService.CreateBroadcast() method. and yes you are right I forgot to mention the method. I'm gonna edit the question now.

Comment: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` looks like a result of `codecs` array getting turned into a string, but that should not happen as a result of simple assignment. I'd suggest attaching a debugger and checking what's actually happening to the Router

Comment: Side note, you're using a class to describe the shape of a plain JavaScript object, Broadcast should probably be an interface instead